# apply discounts to values in json javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an app with 3 items to purchase (3 books: wiz[0], lorax[1], and democrat[2]). These 3 books all cost $24.95, but two books cost $44.90(-$5 Off total), and three books cost $59.85(-$10 Off total). But the 4th or + book should be discounted to $19.95 with no further discounts. I am stuck on my third function "__totalWithDiscounts()". Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I feel like its super simple but I don't know what to do.

```
var cartJSON = [{'id':'wiz','count':0},
           {'id':'gorax','count':0},
           {'id':'democrat','count':0}]

function __updateTheTotal(item,quantity){
  // find book being updated and change the count to the passed quantity
 for (var i=0; i<cartJSON.length; i++) {
  if (cartJSON[i].id == item) {
   cartJSON[i].count = quantity;
   break;
  }
 }
 __totalWithDiscounts();
}

function __totalWithDiscounts(){
 // this function will get the new json data generated by the inputs and apply discounts based on the amount
 var discount_offTwoBooks = Number(5);
 var discount_offThreeBooks = Number(10);
 var priceOfEachBook_default = Number(24.95);
 var priceOfEachBook_afterCountIs4 = Number(19.95);
 var totalOf_wiz = Number(cartJSON[0].count);
 var totalOf_gorax = Number(cartJSON[1].count);
 var totalOf_democrat = Number(cartJSON[2].count);
 var totalOf_all = +totalOf_wiz +totalOf_gorax +totalOf_democrat;
 console.log('total books: '+totalOf_all);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this. Haven't tested this but pretty sure it'd work:

```
    function __totalWithDiscounts(){
     // this function will get the new json data generated by the inputs and apply discounts based on the amount
     var discount_offTwoBooks = Number(5);
     var discount_offThreeBooks = Number(10);
     var priceOfEachBook_default = Number(24.95);
     var priceOfEachBook_afterCountIs4 = Number(19.95);
     var totalOf_wiz = Number(cartJSON[0].count);
     var totalOf_gorax = Number(cartJSON[1].count);
     var totalOf_democrat = Number(cartJSON[2].count);
     var totalOf_all = 0+totalOf_wiz +totalOf_gorax +totalOf_democrat;
     console.log('total books: '+totalOf_all);

    var priceOfAll = 0;
    if(totalOf_all >=4 ) priceOfAll = totalOf_all * priceOfEachBook_afterCountIs4;
    else if(totalOf_all == 3) priceOfAll = priceOfEachBook_default * 3 - discount_offThreeBooks;
    else if(totalOf_all == 2) priceOfAll = priceOfEachBook_default * 2 - discount_offTwoBooks;
    else priceOfAll = priceOfEachBook_default * 1;
  }
```

A bit of advice: use better variable names. And this was a simple logical construct of branching. Not that difficult to grasp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsfiddle with a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/6p1n1tta/3/

```
var totalOf_all = totalOf_wiz + totalOf_gorax + totalOf_democrat;
 var discount = 0;
  switch (totalOf_all) {
    case 1: {
        discount = 0;
      break;
    }
    case 2: {
      discount = discount_offTwoBooks;
      break;
    }
    case 3: {
      discount = discount_offThreeBooks;
      break;
    }
    default: {
      discount = priceOfEachBook_afterCountIs4;
      break;
    }
  }
 var totalPrice = (totalOf_all * priceOfEachBook_default) - discount;

 console.log('total books: ' + totalOf_all + '\n' + 'total price: ' + totalPrice);
```

Also, in your `__updateTheTotal` function, it should be `cartJSON[i].count += quantity;`.  The count won't properly update until you make that change.